# ajax отправка формы

Tags: ajax

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой.
На странице есть форма:

```
<form id="recoverform" class="loginform" action="">
   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
   <button class="btn" onclick="sandEmail();" name="sandBtn">Отправить</button>
   <p>Сообщение с данными для входа будет отправлено на ваш Email</p>
</form>
```

Она отправляется посредством ajax запроса:

```
function sandEmail(){

   $.ajax({
     url:'sendMessage.php',
     type:'post',
     data: $('#recoverform').serialize(),
     success: function(result){
       $(sendForm).next().html(result);
     }

   });
```

}
При нажатии на кнопку происходит следующее. Открывается страница с таки url: http://hostname.ru/login?email=&sandBtn=

Что не так? Почему передаются данные не методом POST, а GET и почему на текущую страницу, а не на php файл без обновления текущей страницы?

Comment: А значения вносятся? `sandBtn` идет без поля `value`, ввод  в поле почты под вопросом... Если просто нажать на кнопку то поведение вполне правильное...

Comment: @DNS Нет, данные не отправляются на файл обработчик, они передаются гетом на текущую страницу.

Comment: Да, поторопился, не все просмотрел - Вы подвешиваете обработчик не на форму, а на кнопку. Метод ПОСТ касается самой формы...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я подправил Ваш первоначальный код, который Вы очень быстро изменили. Здесь нужен только обработчик сабмита формы, который отменяется использованием `event.preventDefault();`, с посылкой ajax-a.

```
<form id="recoverform" class="loginform" action="">
   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
   <button class="btn" name="sendBtn">Отправить</button>
   <p>Сообщение с данными для входа будет отправлено на ваш Email</p>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#recoverform').submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       var sendForm = this;
       $.ajax({
           url:'sendMessage.php',
           type:'post',
           data: $(sendForm).serialize(),
           success: function(result){
               $(sendForm).next().html(result);
           }
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, а что Вы изменили?)

Comment: `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Хах, ребят, я дико прошу прощение, короче не подключил я ajax к странице) Пора пить кофе) Ответ отмечу как правильный, спасибо.